# Next step in this Slitherlink puzzle?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

I am playing this [Slitherlink app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejelta.slitherlink.ads) on Android, and get stuck on this puzzle at the following state: [image]

I made a lot of progress on the right side, but after this I couldn't find anything that I can do, without potentially guessing a very long chain.

Can anyone help me reason the next logical step from this state?

Comment: off-topic, but may I recommend this one? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.boyle.chris.sgtpuzzles
It is completely free and open source, and has a lot of the different puzzles including Slitherlink. Only weirdness about it is that the names are all different, Slitherlink is called "Loopy" for example.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe: I recommend those puzzles as well! They can be played online at [Tatham's website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles) and/or downloaded as stand-alone executables. And my favourite Loopy variant is Cairo.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few places where you can place lines leaving a "2" square.
E.g in the top left:

One edge marked **A** must be a line, so exactly one **B** must also be a line to have two lines around the 2.
So **C must be a line** for the continuation from **B**.

Similarly, one **D** must be a line to continue the loop, so **E must be a line** to have two lines around the 2.

Then, one **F** must be a line to continue from E. That's the only line required for the "1", so **both G's must be blank**.

[image]

And a less obvious example of a pattern where lines touch a 2-square on diagonally opposite corners:
Because of the known lines, the edges marked **A** cannot both be lines, and the edges marked **D** cannot both be lines.
So exactly one **A** and one **D** must be a line to have two lines around the 2-square.
Both of those continue known lines, so **B and E must both be blank**.
(And then **C and F must both be lines** to complete the other 2-squares)

[image]

And some similar stuff on the right hand side:
One **A** must be a line for the 1-square, so **B must be a line** to continue the loop.

And similar to the top-left corner, one of **C** must be a line for the 1-square, so one of **D** must be a line to continue the loop.
Then one of **E** must be a line to have two lines around the 2-square, and **F must be a line** to continue the loop.
So **G must be blank** and all the remaining edges of the 3-square must be lines.

[image]

Comment: Ah, interesting, I guess I shall try this technique on other parts of the board too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For the 1 near the bottom left, the left or bottom edge must be included because of the top-right corner of the bottom-left 3.  So the top of the 1 is not an edge, which determines the 3 edges for the neighboring 3.

[image]

I see now that this method is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink#Diagonals_of_a_3_and_1).

Comment: There was a [recent question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/115835/69582) related to this

Comment: @bobble it's different, right? The other question is when we know one of the vertices on the 3 box is definitely an endpoint, so the opposite corner must not be an endpoint. For this one, it's about one edge of the 3 box being confirmed blank.

Comment: From your explanation, it looked like you were using the rocket pattern with the corner 3 and the 1 to rule out the 1's top edge as a possibility.

Comment: Ah, you mean the reverse, and the corner 3. Hmm, well, I think I can accept that then, although I feel this deduction is much easier than the rocket pattern, where the 3 box is missing one edge. (the fact that this is easy is what made me slightly annoyed that I missed this, actually, haha, I imagine I wouldn't be as annoyed if it were real rocket pattern)

Comment: Yes this can be viewed as the rocket pattern, using the two known corner edges of the corner 3 to deduce the two non-edges of the 1.  But I used only the top-right corner based on the third known edge, so it is a bit simpler.